# Site Collection/Hub Site/Site creation

Tags: hub-site

Afternoon

I'm setting up a Site Collection under which I want four Hub Sites and under there a number of sites for a flat architecture.

So.… I set up the site collection, do a create the hub sites by creating sub sites in the site collection and then registering the sites as Hub sites in SharePoint Admin? Then do I just create a site in SP Admin and associate them with the Hub Site?

I don't I'm going down the right route by creating a sub site under the site collection cause I can't see it in SP Admin to register as a Hub Site.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Hub site IS a site collection.  When you create a site collection, you can register it as a Hub in the SharePoint Admin center.

There is currently no mechanism to have Hub Sites be "under" anything, or any way to connect Hubs together.  Once you register a site collection as a Hub, you can connect other non-Hub sites to it, either through the Admin Center, or through the gear settings in the site you want to connect from.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/planning-hub-sites

Comment: Right! So Site Collection and Hub sites are the same thing only you register a Site Collection as a Hub then you associate sites with the Hubs and they can show up in the nav etc?

Comment: They won't automatically show up in the Nav, but the connected sites do automatically inherit the Hub-level Navigation and Theme.  When you register a site collection is a hub, it gets a new top-level navigation bar immediately above the normal top-level navigation for the site.  Essentially giving you two horizontal navigation bars across the top -- one of which is for your Hub, the other is specific to that site.  You can manually change the links in this navigation bar nearly identically to how you normally change the site's navigation bar.

Comment: Sites connected to the Hub, will automatically get the same Hub-level nav bar above is own site-level navigation, but you can only change that Hub-level navigation from within the Hub.

Comment: How would I edit the top level nav on a site I've associate with a Hub Site? I created a subsite under the HubSite. It showed up in the top nav of a site I associated with the Hub Site. I deleted the sub site, the link is still showing but it's throwing a 404

Comment: Just navigate to the Hub site collection, and assuming you have permission, you will see the `Edit` link in the hub nav bar, then you can add/remove/edit links in the hub-nav.  Also, to clarify, you should not actually be creating subsites in your site collection, the whole intent of Hub sites, is to associate site collection via Hub connections to avoid creating "old fashioned" subsites.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a sub site in modern SharePoint online, you are going against the rules of site creation in modern experience :-), the purpose of hub site is to adhere the flat architecture rather than going with the nested architecture, i. e sub site.... creating the modern site adhering the hub site concept, Microsoft recommends... so I think you need to redesign the site creation architecture, need to go back from sub site to site collection.... and promote any of the site collection (site) as a hub site and registered all needed or related sites to the particular hub site and configure the Mega menu in the hub site and reuse those inside the associated sites... this design will help in the long run. :-)

For details understanding about hub site, please refer the below article :

[Tips to create hub site in SharePoint online – Office 365](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site/)

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, don't create subsites anymore.

Create site collections for everything that should be its own site. Register the "top" level as a Hub site. Register "sub" sites with the desired Hub site.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm now creating sites and associating them with the Hub. Final question is there a way I can display the sites associated with the Hub Site on the Hub Site itself?

Comment: The Hub site has its own navigation which is customisable in the same way as a normal site's top-level and "quick launch" navigation, - look for the "Edit Links" link/button - simply add Titles and URLs of each site you wish displayed there